# c++ unicode writing is not working

Tags: c++, unicode

I am trying to write some Russian unicode text in file by wfstream. Following piece of code has been used for it.

```
wfstream myfile;
locale AvailLocale("Russian");

myfile.imbue(AvailLocale);

myfile.open(L"d:\\example.txt",ios::out);
if (myfile.is_open()) 
{ 
    myfile << L"доброе утро" <<endl;
} 

myfile.flush();
myfile.close();
```

Something unrecognizable is written to the file by executing this code, I am using VS 2008.

Comment: That's Cyrillic, not Greek.

Comment: "доброе утро" is "good morning" in Russian. try "Καλημέρα" instead.

Comment: What encoding have your source file (*.cpp)? it must be UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about imbuing locales in C++, but perhaps it isn't working because you're trying to write Cyrillic characters using the Greek locale?

Comment: I am sorry actually its locale AvailLocale("Russian"); Not Greek, Something is being written to file but when I open this example.txt file in internet explorer browser then it shows me some unreconizable characters ������ ����. And if I copy and paste these "доброе утро" characters in another file say example2.txt manually then its shown correctly

Comment: Why don't you post your exact code instead of something that's been retyped?

Comment: @Jugal Hishore : You are writing to a TXT file then you open it with IE, how can IE know the encoding of a TXT file ? Does the file have the necessary BOM ? Why do you open it with IE in the first place?

Comment: Even If I open it in Notepad++ it shows me the xE4 xEE xE1 xF0 xEE xE5  xF3 xF2 xF0 xEE

Comment: @JugalKishore: That looks like CP-1251 to me (a Windows encoding for Cyrillic characters). This is the default Windows encoding for the Russian locale. It will work when you copy and paste into Notepad because by default it will save it as UTF-16 (or maybe UTF-8) and insert a BOM so that readers of the file can know the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `std::locale("Russian")` the file will be encoded as "Cyrillic (Windows)" (and not some Unicode format) when you use VS2008. If you for example open it with Internet Explorer and change the encoding to Cyrillic (Windows) the characters become visable.

It is more common to store files in some Unicode format.

When I use:

```
const std::locale AvailLocale
      = std::locale(std::locale("Russian"), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>());
```

to store it as UTF-8 and open the file for example in notepad as an UTF-8 file. It see доброе утро

Similarly you can use codecvt_utf16 or some other coding scheme to encode the unicode characters.

codecvt_utf8 is specific for C++11.

Alternatively you can use boost:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html
Or implement something similar yourself (from looking at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/boost/detail/utf8_codecvt_facet.hpp it doesn't seem that complicated).

Or this library: http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: when I use the above code it gives error "error C2039: 'codecvt_utf8' : is not a member of 'std'"

Comment: I have found the reason. It has been added to std in Visual Studio 2010 and I am using VS 2008. Is there any other way to achieve it on VS 2008?

Comment: I also added something on the original encoding. It seems that with your code the file in encoded as "Cyrillic (Windows)".

Comment: Thank you. No kidding, Unicode support in C++ is seemingly a small improvement, but big step for all.